# Calculating frequency of sound of ringing metal coin

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fourier-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, linear-pde, isospectrality

I would like to reproduce the results of [Manas - The music of gold: Can gold counterfeited coins be detected by ear?](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/276297204_The_music_of_gold_Can_gold_counterfeited_coins_be_detected_by_ear), but it skips a lot of steps, and the mathematics behind it is a bit advanced for me (Bessel functions etc.). Summarizing the paper, it shows how to calculate the dominant frequencies of the sound of a ringing metal coin for given dimensions and metal composition, using the formula $f=\frac{h}{2 \pi a^2}\sqrt\frac{E}{12 \rho (1-v^2)}\lambda^2$, with tables for values of each of the physical variables for various metals.

There are a few particular places where I've gotten stuck.

- The "shape factor" $\frac{h}{2 \pi a^2}$ is calculated as 1.44 given values $h=\text{1 mm}$ and $a=\text{21 mm}$ (page 6), but I got the value 0.00036107861.
- The dimensions in these factors do not seem to cancel out, and it doesn't say what is the correct unit to measure in.
- There is a distinction made between a free-standing disc, a clamped disc, and a disc supported on a column, but it is not clear to me how to modify the formula in each case.
- The format of the formula suggests that the values of $\lambda$ are independent of the physical variables, but then there is a table on page 8 where for instance, $\lambda_{2,0}$ has values ranging from 2.21 to 2.33 for different metals.

Edit: To make my question more concrete, I would like to be able to calculate the frequencies for, say, a silver coin with thickness 2mm and diameter 30mm, and determine which mode of testing to use in order to reproduce that spectrum with a real coin. I am not able to get the same result as the paper using their formula, and I don't know what mistake or omission to fix in order to fill that gap.

Comment: Aside from possibly the first, none of these seems like a mathematical issue.

Comment: @LSpice, I'm not sure I agree. I'm asking for help from whoever on this site might know more about the background for these calculations than I do. For instance, how the formula should vary with different boundary conditions is a mathematical question, one not addressed in the paper. Why the eigenvalues are different for different materials, and how to determine them, is a potentially mathematical question. Which units to use in a formula is certainly a mathematical question, at least in an applied sense. I could add more clarification to the question if that would help.

Comment: the paper you cite is not reliable; in the formula for the frequency $a$ should be the radius, not the diameter of the disc; the shape factor is not dimensionless, so a statement that says it equals 1.44 is meaningless; the formula for the frequencies only applies to a clamped unstressed disc; values of $\lambda$ for that case are in Table 3 of [this paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.4719964), which seems a more reliable source --- and yes, this question is quite off-topic here.

Comment: The name of "this paper" [referenced](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377552/calculating-frequency-of-sound-of-ringing-metal-coin#comment957815_377552) by @CarloBeenakker:  [Malhaire - Comparison of two experimental methods for the mechanical characterization of thin or thick films from the study of micromachined circular diaphragms](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4719964).

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, thank you for the explanation and link, that resolves a couple of my questions. I'm sorry if the question is off topic, maybe you can direct me to where it would be more appropriate, or help me to recast it in a more appropriate way. I would also like to understand, if you can direct me to where I can find out more, how the situation would change for a disc that is not clamped around the edge.

Comment: I would try physics.stackechange